# WPF disable button with IDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, vb.net, icommand

I found [this tutorial](http://www.gonetdotnet.info/posts/wpf-articles/wpf-error-validation-and-display) and I was able to implement it.

How can I disable a button when an errors occurs?

I searched a lot over the net, but I can't find a piece of code that resembles mine. (Yes, I know there about a zillion threads about this matter, but I just don't understand it.)

Here is my current code, it's a bit lengthy:

```
Public Class GradeVm
    Implements IDataErrorInfo

    Public Interface IDataErrorInfo
        Default ReadOnly Property Item(columnName As String) As String
        ReadOnly Property [Error]() As String
    End Interface

    #Region "Properties"
    Property Grade As Integer
    Property Adjust As Integer
    #End Region

    Public ReadOnly Property [Error] As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Error
        Get
            Return "Error"
        End Get
    End Property

    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(columnName As String) As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Item
        Get
            Select Case columnName
                Case "Grade"
                    If IsNumeric(Me.Grade) = False Then
                        Return [Error]
                    End If
                Case "Adjust"
                    If IsNumeric(Me.Adjust) = False Then
                        Return [Error]
                    End If
            End Select

            Return ""
        End Get
    End Property
    End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/06/wpf-textbox-validation-idataerrorinfo.html#comment-form) combined with the code here did the trick! Finally!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding button to `RelayCommand`, you can disable the button by setting `CanExecute()` function to return `False` :

```
Public Function CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements ICommand.CanExecute
    Return False
End Function
```

But `RelayCommand` doesn't meant to be used this way. I'd suggest to pick a MVVM framework ([MVVMLight](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) for example), and you'll get better `RelayCommand` implementation ready to use. Then you can use it like this :

```
Private _myCommand As RelayCommand = New RelayCommand(Me.ExecuteCommand, Me.CanExecuteCommand)
Public ReadOnly Property MyCommand As ICommand
    Get
        Return Me._myCommand
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub ExecuteCommand()
    ......
End Sub

Private Function CanExecuteCommand() As Boolean
    'do logic to disable (return false) or enable (return true) button
    'based on specific criteria
    'just for example, disable the button forever :
    Return False
End Function
```

**UPDATE :**

Why you deleted your `RelayCommand` implementation? The 1st approach meant, use `RelayCommand` in your original post, but change return value of `CanExecute()` function to `False` instead of `True`. Then you can use it in `ViewModel` like so :

```
Private _myCommand As RelayCommand = New RelayCommand()
Public ReadOnly Property MyCommand As ICommand
    Get
        Return Me._myCommand
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Could you please give me a workout example? I'm sorry I have to ask, but I'm completely lost!

Comment: Install Mvvmlight from nuget, add 2nd code snippet in this answer to your VM. Assuming you have datacontext set up properly, and button command property bound to `MyCommand`, this should work to disable your button forever.

Comment: I don't want to use extra plugins.

Comment: There are 2 approaches suggested in this answer, I thought you're going with 2nd approach. Anyway, updated my answer to explain more about the 1st approach

Comment: Hi Har, I want to keep it as simple as possible.  
I moved the class RelayCommand to a separate file.

How/where do I trigger/set the MyCommand Property?

Comment: The only time the 'class' I made above is triggered, is when I load the form.
It then colors the textboxen red when the value is wrong, but it never goes back to the class?